# Как поставить ограничение при загрузке файлов через инпут, чтобы можно было грузить только картинки?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как поставить ограничение при загрузке файлов через инпут, чтобы можно было грузить только картинки а не файлы всех типов?

Comment: `accept="image/*"`...

Comment: Ограничение никак нельзя поставить. `accept="image/*"` - установит по умолчанию фильтр на картинки(вообще поведение зависит от ОС).

Answer (score 1):

Можно только если через событие `change`, привязанное к этому самому инпуту:

```
const inputChangeHandler = (event) => {
    if (event.target.files.every(file=>/^image\/.+/.test(file.type))) {
        //все загруженные файлы - картинки
    } else {
        //обратное
    };
}
```